# Unintended scrolling of a grid container

Tags: html, css

Even though my grid container is set to (100vh, 100vw) the contents of the grid still overflows.

The weird thing is that when I open the page, it has the scroll bars and scroll, but when I resize the window and put it back into fullscreen again(meaning the size of the screen is the same), the scroll bars go away!

I don't really know whats causing this, so any help would be appreciated.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


.wrapper {

    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 4fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 7.5fr 7.5fr 2fr 1fr;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
}


.navbar {
    background: pink;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    grid-column: 1/3;
    
}


.webcam {
    background: green;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 2/3;
    
}


.chat {
    background: blue;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 3/4;
    
}


.two-buttons {
    background: brown;
    grid-column: 1/2;
    grid-row: 4/6;
    
}


.screen {

    background: black;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 2/4;
    
}


.bunch-of-buttons {
    background: red;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 4/5;
    
}


.chat-send-button {

    background: yellow;
    grid-column: 2/3;
    grid-row: 5/6;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Focus</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            asdf
        </div>
        <div class="webcam">
            asdf
        </div>
        <div class="chat">
            asdf
        </div>
        <div class="two-buttons">
            asdf
        </div>
        <div class="screen">
            asdf
        </div>
        <div class="bunch-of-buttons">
            asdf
        </div>
        <div class="chat-send-button">
            asdf
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: My monitor is 1280*1024.

Comment: Replace ur wrapper width and height values with 100%, looks like ur viewport is not set up to the right scale and vh and vw relate to the viewport,while % relate to the parent element

Comment: Thanks, however I tried this and with percentages the wrapper actually doesn't fill the whole page.

Comment: It appears as though the problem was with my browser, and weirdly enough its fixed now, should I delete my question? I don't really know.

Comment: don't use vw. Only us vh. elements are by default full width

Comment: Oh I didn't know that, thank you.

Comment: In this case you must also set the parent element to 100% width and height, and if it's still not filling the same to the next parent elememt, and so on until u get what u want :)